# How to merge multiple elements of a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In this instance I have two words (code and question), where after every vowel in them, I want to put a certain sign (in my case I decided for a "#").
I managed to make a list where I have a sign after a certain vowel in a word (e.g. co#de)
Now all that is left, I want to merge those words together. Have I even decided for a right approach here?

I have a list with 6 elements:

```
# there is "#" after every vowel in a word
lst = ["code#", "que#stion", "questi#on", "co#de", "questio#n", "qu#estion"]
```

I want to merge these elements together, so I can get a new list with only two elements.

```
# the two words stay the same, but there are now multiple "#" in every word
new_lst = ["co#de#", "qu#e#sti#o#n"]
```

Is this something that is even possible to do in python?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Can you share some code you wrote to try it

Comment: For merging these elements, I didn't really write anything, since I don't even know how to tackle the problem. That's what i was hoping to find out here.

Answer (score 1):

Is it Okay to start with a fresh un`mark`ed `list` :)

```
>>> poundit = lambda x: ''.join('{}#'.format(y) if y.lower() in ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'] else y for y in x)
>>> lst
['code#', 'que#stion', 'questi#on', 'co#de', 'questio#n', 'qu#estion']
>>> set(poundit(x) for x in (y.replace('#', '') for y in lst))
set(['qu#e#sti#o#n', 'co#de#'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through each letter of each word, making a new word out the old word, appending a '#' when you find a vowel

```
words = ['code', 'question']
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
new_words = []
#Iterate through words
for word in words:
    new_word = ''
    #Iterate through letters
    for letter in word:
        new_word+= letter
        #Add a # when you find a vowel
        if letter in vowels:
            new_word+='#'
    new_words.append(new_word)
print(new_words)
#['co#de#', 'qu#e#sti#o#n']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new_words = []
for word in words:
    temp_word = ""
    for element in word:
        if element not in vowels:
            temp_word += element
        else:
            temp_word += element
            temp_word += "#"
    new_words.append(temp_word)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use regex to do this

```
import re
lst = ["code#", "que#stion", "questi#on", "co#de", "questio#n", "qu#estion"]

def func(x):
   o = ''
   for c in x:
       o += c
       if c.lower() in 'aeiou':
           o += '#'
   return o

x = list(map(func, set(map(lambda x: re.sub('#', '', x), lst))))
print(x)

Out: ['co#de#', 'qu#e#sti#o#n']
```